# HTTP POST Hidden Input Type in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, http, post, ios7

I have looked around the site and I have found some variations of this question, but I can't get it figured out. I am trying to send via POST a Hidden Input value with my iOS application that I am building.

Example of HTML POST I am trying to reproduce in iOS.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<title>Testing</title>
<body>
<form NAME="formName" METHOD="post"
ACTION="https://samplewebservice.com">
<input type=hidden name="transactionMode" value="SendValues" >
<b>XML Message body:</b>
<TEXTAREA class="xmlbox" name="Request" COLS=100 ROWS=10 >
XML Request being sent. 
 </TEXTAREA>
<br>
<input TYPE=submit class=input VALUE="Send Request">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is how the webservice is setup to be used. However I am able to send my XML but the Web Service that I am trying to send to keeps saying that the Request parameter is missing. Please find below my Obj-C code of ow I atmpeted to solve it.

```
    NSString *_xmlDoc = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@=%@&%@=%@", @"transactionMode", @"SendValues", @"Request", @"XML Request being sent. "];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [_xmlDoc length]];
    NSData *postData = [_xmlDoc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://samplewebservice.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *serviceRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    [serviceRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [serviceRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Error in the console from the response from the webservice is the following.

```
 <description>Mandatory request parameter is missing: Request</description>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. First time poster so please let me know if I missed something.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my error was. It would seem that I was missing a few needed HTTP Headers. Please find my answer below.

```
  NSURL *serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://somewebservice.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *serviceRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
[serviceRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[serviceRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[serviceRequest setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[serviceRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

I added the spplcation/x-www-form-urlencoded and it worked like a charm.

Hope that this helps someone.